# How to create a dotted line in center of section of website

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, alignment

I'm trying to make an "Our Process" section on a Wordpress site that looks like this: https://rfqedge.com/how-it-works/

How can I make a dotted line like that (preferably animated like on linked site, but unnecessary if it considerably complicates things)?

I'm a UI designer and don't know anything about programming, so please try to simplify things if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This dotted line in center using css is

```
.step .text-frame .dashed-line .line {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 1;
background: url(images/border5.png) repeat-y;
}
```

I hope it's helps you

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can apply CSS to create a dotted line where you want to create.
you can use the code and choose your color on the line as well as set where you want the line

under the body section

`<body>
<hr></hr>
</body>`

Under the style section

```
`<style>hr{border:none; border-top:2px dotted #f00; color:#fff; background-color:#fff; height:1px; width:100%; margin-top:50px;}</style>`
```